# Copy from worksheet to worksheet in different workbooks with IF condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a range in a row from 1 worksheet to another in different workbooks with a "IF" condition in column "A", e.g.

IF column "A" equals "H" then copy from range: "B" to "DJ" from test.xls/worksheet1 to "A1" in test1.xls/worksheet1
else IF column "A" equals "D" then copy from range: "B" to "C" from test.xls/worksheet1 to "A1" in test1.xls/worksheet1

I only managed to copy the the first range over to test1.xls/worksheet1, but tried several conditional methods to do the second range. I can't seem to do it.

My Code:

```
`Sub OpenAndCopy()
 Dim wbCopy As Workbook
 Dim wsCopy As Worksheet

 Dim rngCopy As Range
 Dim wbPaste As Workbook
 Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
 Dim rngPaste As Range
 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim lCol As Long 

 Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEMP\TEST.XLS") 'change path
 Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range("BK")

 Set wbPaste = Workbooks("TEST1.XLS")
 Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'paste to different sheet?
 Set rngPaste = wsPaste.Range("A1") 'change this if needed

 rngCopy.Copy
 rngPaste.PasteSpecial
 wbCopy.Close

 End Sub`
```

Appreciate whatever comments and assistance/help I can get to insert the correct VBA to do it without errors. Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you looping through several rows to check the contents of column A? Why does your code refer to BK?

Comment: Yes, I probably may need to loop through several rows to check the contents of column A.  Only 2 in column A - "H" and "D".  Actually "BK" is not the correct one which I listed, it is "B:C"

Comment: Sorry said incorrectly in above comment, the BK is actually "B:DK" for column A = "H" and "B:C" for column A="D".